# SVN Merge - Client or Server?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, svn-merge, data-loss

When 2 users change the same file (in the same branch) and check their code into SVN, SVN will (after asking the second user to do an update) auto merge the files and try to resolve any conflicts.

Does this merge process happen on the client or on the server?

(more info: I am using Tortoise SVN  1.7.11 on the client, and the server version is 1.5.1, we recently had an auto-merge delete some data and I'm wondering if this is an issue with the code merge in Tortoise or the older server code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Tortoise SVN thing, and thus on the client. The SVN server will actually kick it back and tell you youre not up to date. Weird that tortoise does that... Doesnt seem like a feature anyone in their right mind would ever want...

Comment: Remember, TortoiseSVN delegates the actual operations to the commandline SVN exe. So it might be passing parameters that are causing this behaviour

Comment: TortoiseSVN does *not* "delegate" the operations. It has its own built-in copy of the Subversion client libraries.

Comment: Tortoise doesn't "auto merge" like this that I've seen - it asks you if you want it to update and then re-try the commit (unless doing it automatically is an option you can enable & I haven't looked for it)

Comment: @alroc: It must be an option then. I dont use tortise much if at all because im rarely in a a windows environment, but i can say this isnt done on the svn server implementation, and I have never seen it do this in another svn client (command line, eclipse, SCPlugin, etc..) so by process of elimination its gott be something in tortoise... EDIT: Jsut check the settings in 1.6 (which is old of course) and didnt see anything related.

Comment: @alroc yes, sorry my mistake, when I say 'auto merge' it's not completely automatic, it asks you to do an update and when you do the update it automatically merges and alerts you if there are conflicts. The problem is that (twice now) these merges have resulted in loss of data - I've been using SVN for around 7 years and never had such a severe issue, perhaps it is the Tortoise/server version mismatch.

Comment: my question is whether the process that does the merge of the 2 files is happening on the server or client, I guess this applies if I'm using the SVN command line client too

Comment: All merges happen on the client. If you can create a script which reproduces a true data loss condition (and not user error/misunderstanding), I'm sure the Subversion developers would love to see it so they can fix it.

Comment: Still not traced the source of the error but likely due to a file being open and not updated by the IDE when doing an update/merge - then overriding the changes when checked back in.